# get error in conn.Open(); in Asp.net visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, oledbconnection

I have problem in my connection string visual studio 2012 C# asp.net.
Example :

public partial class Search_Report : System.Web.UI.Page
{

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Data Source=orcl;User ID=hr;Password=hr;Unicode=True");

void select()
{
    //select statement into DataTable
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        DataTable DtTabledaily = new DataTable();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM MAGANGMAYORA where rekening_no = '5300303139'";

        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);

        oda.Fill(DtTabledaily);

        GridView1.DataSource = DtTabledaily;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        oda.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        lblerror.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

But when run program, i get error : `An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.`

So, I change my conn to become :

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=orcl;User ID=hr;Password=hr;Unicode=True");
```

I run program again,but i get another error in `conn.Open();`
the Error says :

```
 [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Invalid connection string attribute.
```

In my Web.Config connection string :

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=orcl;User ID=hr;Password=hr;Unicode=True"
      providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

someone help me. I dont know how to fix this error in conn.Open();
Thanks.

Comment: you can check out how to write connection string https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: If you are connecting to an Oracle database then you should provide a valid connection string for Oracle. The code uses an hand made connectionstring that could work for Sql Server not for Oracle. Why don't you use the connection in your Web.Config? And finally, there are native providers for Oracle. No need to use a generic OleDb provider

Answer (score 0):

I change Oledb to OracleConnection, it's fix my problem . Thanks for advice.